# How to convert unix timestamp in Hive to unix timestamp in Spark for format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, hive, apache-spark-sql

One of my tables contains date columns with the format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ` and I need to convert this into `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format.

I'm able to convert this in Hive but when I do the same in spark, it throws error.

### Hive:

```sql
select order.admit_date, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(order.ADMIT_DATE,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as ADMIT_DATE
from daily_orders order;
```

```text
admit_date                       admit_date
--------------                  --------------
2021-12-20T00:00:00.000Z        2021-12-20 00:00:00
```

### Spark

```scala
spark.sql("select order.admit_date, from_unixtime(to_timestamp(order.ADMIT_DATE,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as modified_date from daily_orders order).show();
```

Output:

> :1: error: ')' expected but character literal found.

I have also tried to escape the quotes, but did not get through.

```scala
spark.sql("select order.admit_date, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(order.ADMIT_DATE,"yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as modified_date from daily_orders order limit 10").show()
```

Output:

> :1: error: ')' expected but ':' found.

Is there a common syntax that converts both in Hive and Spark. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You have some escaping problems in your query (using `"` inside another `"`). You can use use multi-line string to escape them.

However, this can actually be done using only `to_timestamp` function:

```scala
spark.sql("""
    select  '2021-12-20T00:00:00.000Z'               as admit_date, 
            to_timestamp('2021-12-20T00:00:00.000Z') as modified_date
    """).show()

//+------------------------+-------------------+
//|admit_date              |modified_date      |
//+------------------------+-------------------+
//|2021-12-20T00:00:00.000Z|2021-12-20 00:00:00|
//+------------------------+-------------------+
```

See docs [Spark Datetime Patterns for Formatting and Parsing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)

##### Edit:

If you want to keep the same syntax as Hive:

```scala
spark.sql("""
  select  '2021-12-20T00:00:00.000Z' as admit_date, 
          from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2021-12-20T00:00:00.000Z', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as modified_date
""").show()

//+------------------------+-------------------+
//|admit_date              |modified_date      |
//+------------------------+-------------------+
//|2021-12-20T00:00:00.000Z|2021-12-20 00:00:00|
//+------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @blackbishop. But please throw some light, I need to use a function that works in both Hive and Spark since my query translates to Spark during job execution.

Comment: Yes, your solution works. But the framework we used here  unable to recognize this double quotes and spaces.